# Why do these declarations (for the same pattern) satisfy the type checker?

Tags: types, idris, proof-of-correctness

I'm following along with the amazing TDDwI, writing a simple `removeElem`.

Four questions about it:

1. why can I write 3 declarations for the same pattern?
2. what's the difference between `absurd` and `impossible`?
3. in that 3rd case that returns `[]`, `[]` is a value, therefore... proof that `xs` had an `a` to remove, and did... right?
4. if I remove all 3 of them, the function is still total, and I have an inexplicable tickle that something weird's going on. ?. (i think that's a question)

---

```
removeElem : (value : a)
          -> (xs : Vect (S n) a) 
          -> (prf : Elem value xs) 
          -> Vect n a
removeElem value (value :: ys) Here = ys
removeElem {n = Z} value (y :: []) (There later) = absurd later -- ??
removeElem {n = Z} value (y :: []) (There later) impossible     -- ??
removeElem {n = Z} value (y :: []) (There later) = []           -- ??
removeElem {n = (S k)} value (y :: ys) (There later) = 
  y :: removeElem value ys later
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why can I write 3 declarations for the same pattern?

Because in this case (`y :: []`) you are dealing with a one-element vector.
This means that `later` has type `Elem value []`, i.e. there is an element `value` in the empty list, which is *absurd*. Recall that `absurd` has type `Uninhabited t => t -> a`, which reads as "if a type `t` is uninhabited and you have an inhabitant of that type, then you can construct an inhabitant of an *arbitrary* type `a`". So, you just need `Elem x []` to have an implementation of that interface (it's [here](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/f9846579db29d8f2f6f383f5e3162581ad568935/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr#L607)). That's why `absurd later` works.

`impossible` works because Idris is capable of performing all the above reasoning on its own.

> what's the difference between `absurd` and `impossible`?

The `impossible` *keyword* can be used to rule out a case that doesn’t type-check, while `absurd` is just a *lemma*, so everything must typecheck if you use it.

> in that 3rd case that returns `[]`, `[]` is a value, therefore... proof that `xs` had an `a` to remove, and did... right?

Yes, it is correct. `removeElem` takes a value, a vector of some positive length, a proof that the value belongs to the vector and returns a vector of the decremented-by-one length. If you take a one-element vector, you can just *ignore* the value and the proof and immediately return the empty vector. My point being you don't have to use the proof, it gives you additional guarantees but you are free to ignore them.

> if I remove all 3 of them, the function is still total, and I have an inexplicable tickle that something weird's going on

Everything is fine here, the function still works -- Idris lets you omit impossible cases:

```
removeElem {n = Z} value (y :: []) (There later) impossible
```

Answer (score 1):

The situation is impossible so it does not matter what you do. If one equals two then the moon is made of cheese is a true statement since one is not equal to two. `absurd` is a function of type `Uninhabited t => t -> a`. Idris knows that the situation is impossible so you don't have to handle it.

You can even return the string "Hi" by proving `Vect 0 a = String`

```
removeElem : (value : a)
    -> (xs : Vect (S n) a) 
    -> (prf : Elem value xs) 
    -> Vect n a
removeElem value (value :: ys) Here = ys
removeElem {n = Z} value (y :: []) (There later) = absurd later -- ??
removeElem {n = Z} value (y :: []) (There later) impossible     -- ??
removeElem {a} {n = Z} value (y :: []) (There later) = rewrite (the (Vect 0 a = String) (absurd later)) in "Hi"           -- ??
removeElem {n = (S k)} value (y :: ys) (There later) = y :: removeElem value ys later
```

Comment: "does not matter what you do" > could you clarify? I'm not able to place other values instead of `[]`. And when would I choose `absurd` instead of `impossible`?

Comment: @Josh.F You can literally return any value since you can use absurd to prove anything